# When should or can I make my posts as "community wiki"?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, posts

As I mentioned in the title, in what situation should I make my Questions and answers as "community wiki"?

Comment: Questions or answers? If the former only mods can make a question CW before the automatic conversion after so many edits or answers. If the latter, then totally up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think new users mark their own answers as Community Wiki too frequently. There are a handful of cases where CW is the right approach, but those are almost always Giant Lists of Resources. When in doubt, don't bother. :)